# Canonical form by J. A Green

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Let $f(x)=x^d-a_{d-1}x^{d-1}\cdots-a_0$ be a irreducible polynomial over finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, $C(f)$ be its company matrix. Let $A$ be a matrix with minimum polynomial $m(x)$. For the sake of simplicity of notation we assume $m(x)=f(x)^3$. Then in "lectures in abstract algebra" by Jacobson, we can find the canonical form of $A$ is :

$$B=\left (\begin{array}{cccc}
C(f) & & & \\
N & C(f) & & \\
 & N & C(f) &
\end{array}
\right ),
$$
where the entries of  $N$ are all zero, except  for a coefficient unity in one corner. Since Jacobson give the basis, so this canonical form is esay to understand.

But in the paper "The characters of the finite general linear groups" by J. A. Green, the canonical form is

$$C=\left (\begin{array}{cccc}
C(f) & I_d & & \\
& C(f) & I_d & \\
 & & C(f) &
\end{array}
\right ).$$

So my question is: 1. Why $B$ and $C$ are similar?
2. How we find the minimum polynomial of $C$?
3. Why we need the canonical form $C$ when we have $B$?

Comment: I changed \mathbb{F_q} to \mathbb{F}_q.  I hope the reasons why the former is a solecism are clear. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Personally I find $C$ a more natural canonical form, since it generalizes the Jordan Form in a natural way. The minimal polynomial of $C$ is $f(x)^3$. It clearly has to be a power of $f(x)$ in order to get $0$'s on the diagonal, and $f(C)$ has the nonzero entries $f'(C(f))$ in the blocks immediately above the main diagonal, so the minimal polynomial of $f(C)$ is $x^3$. Then $B$ and $C$ are similar because they both have the same minimal polynomial with degree equal to that of the matrix, so they define isomorphic cyclic modules.

Comment: Thank Prof. Holt. I think I understand this.